# Postfix rejects all incoming emails

Tags: debian, postfix

My email server worked fine till now but for unknown reasons, possibly after setting up forced TLS connection, I am no longer able to receive emails; I did test it during the TLS configuration though, and I'm pretty sure it was working at the time. Sending still works, so does connecting and using Roundcube.

If have tried cleaning up both my master.cf and main.cf but to no avail, and I cannot understand what is happening.

What's bugging me the most is that it seems the restrictions list used by postfix is the one for the relay and not the recipient and I cannot fathom why it would no use the recipient's.

`Postfix version: 2.11.3`

The log file (debug enabled):

```
Nov 13 00:08:01 sd-123 postfix/smtpd[6005]: generic_checks: name=reject_unknown_sender_domain status=0
Nov 13 00:08:01 sd-123 postfix/smtpd[6005]: >>> END Sender address RESTRICTIONS <<<
Nov 13 00:08:01 sd-123 postfix/smtpd[6005]: >>> START Recipient address RESTRICTIONS <<<
Nov 13 00:08:01 sd-123 postfix/smtpd[6005]: generic_checks: name=permit_mynetworks
Nov 13 00:08:01 sd-123 postfix/smtpd[6005]: permit_mynetworks: mail-il1-f172.google.com 209.85.166.172
Nov 13 00:08:01 sd-123 postfix/smtpd[6005]: match_hostname: mail-il1-f172.google.com ~? 127.0.0.0/8
Nov 13 00:08:01 sd-123 postfix/smtpd[6005]: match_hostaddr: 209.85.166.172 ~? 127.0.0.0/8
Nov 13 00:08:01 sd-123 postfix/smtpd[6005]: match_hostname: mail-il1-f172.google.com ~? [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104
Nov 13 00:08:01 sd-123 postfix/smtpd[6005]: match_hostaddr: 209.85.166.172 ~? [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104
Nov 13 00:08:01 sd-123 postfix/smtpd[6005]: match_hostname: mail-il1-f172.google.com ~? [::1]/128
Nov 13 00:08:01 sd-123 postfix/smtpd[6005]: match_hostaddr: 209.85.166.172 ~? [::1]/128
Nov 13 00:08:01 sd-123 postfix/smtpd[6005]: match_hostname: mail-il1-f172.google.com ~? 88.191.5.85/32
Nov 13 00:08:01 sd-123 postfix/smtpd[6005]: match_hostaddr: 209.85.166.172 ~? 88.191.5.85/32
Nov 13 00:08:01 sd-123 postfix/smtpd[6005]: match_list_match: mail-il1-f172.google.com: no match
Nov 13 00:08:01 sd-123 postfix/smtpd[6005]: match_list_match: 209.85.166.172: no match
Nov 13 00:08:01 sd-123 postfix/smtpd[6005]: generic_checks: name=permit_mynetworks status=0
Nov 13 00:08:01 sd-123 postfix/smtpd[6005]: generic_checks: name=reject_unauth_destination
Nov 13 00:08:01 sd-123 postfix/smtpd[6005]: reject_unauth_destination: me@myaddress.com
Nov 13 00:08:01 sd-123 postfix/smtpd[6005]: permit_auth_destination: me@myaddress.com
Nov 13 00:08:01 sd-123 postfix/smtpd[6005]: ctable_locate: move existing entry key me@myaddress.com
Nov 13 00:08:01 sd-123 postfix/smtpd[6005]: generic_checks: name=reject_unauth_destination status=0
Nov 13 00:08:01 sd-123 postfix/smtpd[6005]: generic_checks: name=permit_sasl_authenticated
Nov 13 00:08:01 sd-123 postfix/smtpd[6005]: generic_checks: name=permit_sasl_authenticated status=0
Nov 13 00:08:01 sd-123 postfix/smtpd[6005]: generic_checks: name=reject
## ERROR HERE ## Nov 13 00:08:01 sd-123 postfix/smtpd[6005]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mail-il1-f172.google.com[209.85.166.172]: 554 5.7.1 <me@myaddress.com>: Recipient address rejected: Access denied; from=<me@gmail.com> to=<me@myaddress.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-il1-f172.google.com>
Nov 13 00:08:01 sd-123 postfix/smtpd[6005]: generic_checks: name=reject status=2
Nov 13 00:08:01 sd-123 postfix/smtpd[6005]: >>> END Recipient address RESTRICTIONS <<<
Nov 13 00:08:01 sd-123 postfix/smtpd[6005]: report recipient to all milters (flags=0x1)
Nov 13 00:08:01 sd-123 postfix/smtpd[6005]: > mail-il1-f172.google.com[209.85.166.172]: 554 5.7.1 <me@myaddress.com>: Recipient address rejected: Access denied
```

Here's the output of `postconf -nf`:

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
config_directory = /etc/postfix
debug_peer_list = 209.85.166.0/24
html_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix/html
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 1280000000
milter_connect_macros = i j {daemon_name} v {if_name} _
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 6
mydestination = myaddress.com mail.myaddress.com, sd-123.hoster.com,
    localhost.hoster.com, localhost
myhostname = myaddress.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 some.ip.addr/32
myorigin = /etc/mailname
non_smtpd_milters = unix:/opendkim/opendkim.sock,unix:/opendmarc/opendmarc.sock
policyd-spf_time_limit = 3600
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/letsencrypt/live/myaddress.com/fullchain.pem
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
smtpd_milters =
    unix:/spamass/spamass.sock,unix:/opendkim/opendkim.sock,unix:/opendmarc/opendmarc.sock
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks,
    check_policy_service unix:private/policyd-spf, reject_unauth_pipelining,
    reject_invalid_hostname, reject_non_fqdn_sender,
    reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
    reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net,
    reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org, reject_rbl_client dnsbl.sorbs.net,
    reject_unauth_destination, permit
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination,
    permit_sasl_authenticated, reject
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated,
    permit_tls_clientcerts, reject_non_fqdn_sender, reject_unknown_sender_domain
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/letsencrypt/live/myaddress.com/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/myaddress.com/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/myaddress.com/privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2,!SSLv3
smtpd_tls_protocols = !SSLv2,!SSLv3
smtpd_tls_security_level = encrypt
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
virtual_alias_maps =
    mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf,mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-email2email.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
```

Output of `postconf -Mf`:

```
smtp       inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
submission inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
    -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
    -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
    -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
    -o smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot
    -o smtpd_sasl_path=private/auth
    -o smtpd_sasl_security_options=noanonymous
    -o smtpd_sender_login_maps=mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-email2email.cf
    -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_tls_clientcerts,reject_non_fqdn_sender,reject_unknown_sender_domain
    -o smtpd_sasl_local_domain=$myhostname
pickup     unix  n       -       -       60      1       pickup
cleanup    unix  n       -       -       -       0       cleanup
qmgr       unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
tlsmgr     unix  -       -       -       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite    unix  -       -       -       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
defer      unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
trace      unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
verify     unix  -       -       -       -       1       verify
flush      unix  n       -       -       1000?   0       flush
proxymap   unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix  -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp       unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
relay      unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
showq      unix  n       -       -       -       -       showq
error      unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
retry      unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
discard    unix  -       -       -       -       -       discard
local      unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual    unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp       unix  -       -       -       -       -       lmtp
anvil      unix  -       -       -       -       1       anvil
scache     unix  -       -       -       -       1       scache
maildrop   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=DRhu
    user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
uucp       unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=Fqhu
    user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
ifmail     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=F user=ftn
    argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=Fq.
    user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix - n       n       -       2       pipe flags=R
    user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop}
    ${user} ${extension}
mailman    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=FR
    user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py ${nexthop}
    ${user}
policyd-spf unix -       n       n       -       0       spawn user=policyd-spf
    argv=/usr/bin/policyd-spf
```

Relevant submission conf from master.cf:

```
submission inet n - - - - smtpd                                                                                                                                                                                     
 -o syslog_name=postfix/submission                                                                                                                                                                                  
 -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt                                                                                                                                                                                
 -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes                                                                                                                                                                                      
 -o smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot                                                                                                                                                                                         
 -o smtpd_sasl_path=private/auth                                                                                                                                                                                    
 -o smtpd_sasl_security_options=noanonymous                                                                                                                                                                         
 -o smtpd_sender_login_maps=mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-email2email.cf                                                                                                                                                 

 #-o smtpd_sender_restrictions=reject_sender_login_mismatch -- ORIGINAL // new value was extracted from main.cf                                                                                                     
 -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_tls_clientcerts,reject_non_fqdn_sender,reject_unknown_sender_domain                                                                

 -o smtpd_sasl_local_domain=$myhostname                                                                                                                                                                             
# -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject                                                                                                                                                      
#-o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=reject_non_fqdn_recipient,reject_unknown_recipient_domain,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject ;; original value, but main.cf should be better
```

Relevant conf from main.cf:

```
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_tls_clientcerts, reject_non_fqdn_sender, reject_unknown_sender_domain
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =                                                                                                                                                                                      
                             permit_sasl_authenticated,                                                                                                                                                             
                             permit_mynetworks,                                                                                                                                                                     
                             check_policy_service unix:private/policyd-spf,                                                                                                                                         
                             reject_unauth_pipelining,                                                                                                                                                              
                             reject_invalid_hostname,                                                                                                                                                               
                             reject_non_fqdn_sender,                                                                                                                                                                
                             reject_unknown_sender_domain,                                                                                                                                                          
                             reject_non_fqdn_recipient,                                                                                                                                                             
                             reject_unknown_recipient_domain,                                                                                                                                                       
                             reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net,                                                                                                                                                      
                             reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org,                                                                                                                                                    
                             reject_rbl_client dnsbl.sorbs.net,                                                                                                                                                     
                             reject_unauth_destination,                                                                                                                                                             
                             permit
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = encrypt
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
```

EDIT:
Removed `-o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject` from `master.cf`, added output of `postconf -Mf`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A friend of mine found the issue. Postfix evaluates all restriction lists, including the relay one for received emails. Since my configuration had a "reject" at the end of `smtpd_relay_restrictions`, the `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` was never evaluated. Changing the `reject` to `defer_unauth_destination` did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

postconf program shows by default ONLY the content of main.cf but you have some service configurations in master.cf as well (and postconf expects a special '-M' flag to show it to you). The smtpd service looks like its configured to accept emails only from authenticated clients:

```
-o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
```

Comment: I have commented out the relevant line, but I still have the same issue :( I updated my question adding the postconf -M (thanks, didn't know about that)